# Correlated Subquery appears to use circular logic

Tags: mysql, correlated-subquery

I googled correlated subquery, and it gave me the below example. However, it appears in the outer query, that department id will be determined by a dynamic salary, which in turn, is determined by a relationship between `department_id` in the outer query and `department_id` in the inner query. This seems like very circular logic. How can both department_ids have a relationship when salary is not yet determined?

[image]

Comment: @ysth Can you direct me to an article on order of operations? Shouldn't the entire subquery resolve BEFORE the outer query? And if the outer department ID exists already, doesn't the WHERE occur before the SELECT?

Comment: expanded my comment into an answer; let me know if that doeesn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing the order of operations.  The correlated subquery is essentially a join; in principle it will be performed for all rows (though in practice there is often some optimization) *before the where conditions are applied*.  And joins (again, in principal) execute first and find all the combined source rows that then are filtered by where conditions, then grouped by group bys, etc.

Essentially that's what a correlated subquery is: a subquery that *doesn't* resolve without information from the outer rows.

Does the equivalent

```
select e.salary, e.department_id
from employees e
join (
    select department_id, avg(salary) avg_salary
    from employees
    group by department_id
) department_average
    using (department_id)
where e.salary > department_average.salary
```

also confuse you?

Just like with the equivalent join, the optimizer *may* defer the subquery until after some where conditions have filtered some source rows if possible (or even reverse the order of the join); here that is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Think of this pseudocode:

```
for each employee 'E'
do
  select all the employees in the same department.
  calculate the average salary of those employees.
  if the salary for employee 'E' is greater than the resulting average, 
    then list that employee, 
    otherwise, skip that employee.
done
```

So the subquery calculates the average salary of all employees in the same department as the employee being examined in the outer query. To do this, it needs to filter by the `outer.department_id`.

The example is meant to demonstrate that in a correlated subquery, the subquery is *not* evaluated before the outer query. It must be evaluated repeatedly, once for each row of the outer query,<sup>*</sup> because it will be compared to each respective employee's salary in turn.

The example query actually has a stylistic mistake, in my opinion. The `GROUP BY department_id` is superfluous, because by definition the subquery matches only one `department_id` each time it runs. So there will only be one group in each evaluation of the subquery regardless.

---

<sup>*</sup> Or at least the subquery is evaluated once for each distinct value it's compared to from the outer query. Some databases have this optimization.